# NodeJs app as self contained windows service, is it possible?

Tags: node.js, windows

I would like to prepare a NodeJS app that host Web API and it is self contained (Node JS is built in)
Additionally. I would install that app as windows service. Is it possible?

For now I was able to build NodeJS with WebAPI. I used [pkg npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) to create self contained app. Also I create a WIX project that creates MSI file. During installation all files are copied and new windows service is created. Unfortunately, when new service is started, application is timeout with error:

```
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Foo service to connect.
Product: XXX -- Error 1920. Service 'XXX' failed to start.  Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.
```

Did I missed something? For sure app has sufficient privileges and works fine.

I have seen that I can use [os-service npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-service) to create service but it requires not self contained application, NODEJS has to be pre installed as separate component.

Comment: I am running into the same situation, were able to find a way to package the node app as a self contained app, and at the same time install/run it as a windows service?